# how to calculate % in PPS 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, ssas, mdx, performancepoint

i have these columns in the table and made this table as the FACT table and also using time intelligence filter in the PPS2010..
i have measures , sum (materials), sum (sales) and sum (material_%)

in the PPS dashboard design i have included this cube and all the measures.. and using an analytic chart..
i have developed separate graphs for each columns (material, sales, material_%)..

for the sales and materials there is no problem , when i use the time filter 
in the material_% graph  i used the time filter  current quarter in months   (showing three months ) shows the correct value..

when i use the current quarter filter (sum of all the 3 months)

its showing  146%  (83 +33 +30) --> for actual values

and   150 % ( 50+50+50) --> for target values

actually it showed show me  46% for actual and  50% for target ,

it should be  sum of material in all the 3 months  / sum of sales in all the 3 months but its just calculating sum of material_% column of all the 3  months

time filter :  year :: Halfyear ::quarter:: Month::Day

### DataBase Table:

```
 Month             Year       Material   sales   Material_%  [ material / sales]
 Jan_Act          2011        500         600       83
 Jan_target       2011        400         800       50
 Feb_Act          2011        300         900       33
 Feb_target       2011        300         600       50
 Mar_Act          2011        300         900       30
 Mar_target       2011        300         600       50
 ...... 
 Jan_Act          2012        0            0         0
 Jan_target       2012        600        1000       60
 .............
 Dec_Act          2012         0           0         0
 Dec_target       2012        600         800       75
```

### MDX Query:

```
SELECT
 HIERARCHIZE( { [Time_dim].[Year - Half Year - Quarter - Month - Date].DEFAULTMEMBER } )ON COLUMNS,

 HIERARCHIZE( { [Ven Bi Actfctmaster].[Act Fct].&[ACTUAL], [Ven Bi Actfctmaster].[Act Fct].&[TARGET] } )ON ROWS
 FROM [Vin Finance]
WHERE ( [Measures].[Materials - Ven Bifullrptmaster] )
```

Please help me to sort out this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this issue by changing the measure of '%' columns  from sum to averageofchild in the property tab..